# Getting started with DropboxAPI, class not found

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I'm trying to use the Dropbox API for the first time, but i'm getting this error when launching my app.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.client2.session.Session$AccessType
```

I saw on Dropbox forums a guy with the same problem, and the solution was to rename the class path to libs/ instead of lib/. I did it and didn't work.

I get the error here:

```
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have required jars in lib folder?

Comment: How do you compile and launch your app?

Comment: I have imported all three jars on the sdk lib folder ( dropbox-android-sdk-1.3.jar,
httpmime-4.0.3.jar,
json_simple-1.1.jar)

Comment: Just like i always do, F11 and debug.. I've cleaned my project already, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, the problem was the classPath.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly did you solve it? Been scratching my head with this thing for like 3 hours now.

Comment: On you project, create a folder called libs and put the jar there, after, click with the right button ->Build Path->Add to BuildPath.

Comment: @Markissimo Adding jar files to libs folder give me an error like this  **Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**

Comment: I went into Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Class File, and clicked on the whole dropbox sdk folder. It finally worked after that. Also make sure you follow the suggestions of the rest of the page as well, as I did before trying to change it.

Answer (score 7):

This problem appeared when I imported dropbox jars in the next way:
eclipse project menu -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs;

After that, I revert changes, create folder 'libs' in Project Explorer, in 'libs' folder menu select 'Import...' -> File System. Select path and import all jars into 'libs' project folder.
Problem disappear.

Comment: This worked for me. Although to be clear, I just created a folder called 'libs' in the root of my project, and then physically dragged all the dropbox jars into that folder. I've set to build automatically, so the problem was resolved immediately.

Comment: Actually, no, now the Android SDK and/or eclipse (kepler) has suddenly decided that it can't find the Dropbox jars. I've done nothing different with my setup. Seriously, what is going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add all reference libraries in both the lib and libs folder before it worked, so something is clearly wrong, and for some reason it needs apache-mime4j-0.6 in the lib folder, but the example project from Dropbox on how to implement it don't? can someone from the Dropbox Team deliberate on this? Note: the application used the previous deprecated api, and when I tried updating it with the newest I got this error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.dropbox.client2.session.Session$AccessType

on

```
private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in Eclipse (Luna) I could resolve the error by Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order And Export and then putting a tick on (in my case for Dropbox 1.6.3) the two Dropbox jar files. 
Followed by the usual clean project and run.

This is reproducable by removing the checks marks from the boxes in the Order and Export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of the project libs, its correct name is libs.[image]